# どの object も = "whichever"?

Tags: grammar

I think in the example below, どのダンジョンも・・・ means "whichever dungeon". The advice applies to any dungeon in the game. Can somebody confirm this for me please?

> **どのダンジョンも**、前半はダンジョンアイテム探し、後半は入手したダンジョンアイテムを使っての攻略となる。ダンジョンアイテムはボスにも有効だ。

I imagine this is a standard pattern but I can't say I have seen it a lot in my experiences of Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“どのAも” means that the sentence applies to every A.
Thus, your interpretation is correct.